# How to Preventing create table/view on my table/view that i granted to another schema/user> (ORALCE/SQLPLUS)

Tags: sqlplus, sql-grant, create-view

I have following scenario, is this possible to oe schema to select only, but not create table/view from hr table?

1. table "Employees" created and have data  hr schema
2. granted read access to oe schema --> grant read on employees to oe;
3. connected to oe schema
4. create View V_Employees as select * from hr.employees;  --- i do not want oe schema create view from my table
5. select * from hr.employees; -- this can be allowed

I am expecting OE schema should not be able to create view/table from my hr schema table that granted select/read privilage